# JWT.decode JWT::IncorrectAlgorithm (Expected a different algorithm)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

Trying to encode and decode an ES256 key with the jtw gem and it errors when I try to decode.

```
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(private_key_string)

JWT.encode(
      {
        iss: "1234567890",
        iat: Time.now.to_i
      },
      private_key,
      "ES256",
      {
        alg: "ES256",
        kid: "1234567890",
        typ: "JWT"
      }
    )
```

Comment: You will need to post additional code but this is likely caused by a simple typo. The functionality works as expected when the correct arguments are passed [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/FirebrickFortunateOperatingenvironment#main.rb)

Answer (score 0):

You are sharing your JWT.encode code, however, it seems that the error is in your JWT.decode, please share the code where you are decoding the token.

Try the next:

```rb
    JWT.encode(
      {
        iss: "1234567890",
        iat: Time.now.to_i
      },
      private_key,
      "ES256"
      # this is your extra parameter, just remove it
    )
```

Looking for the documentation, the syntax to encode is JWT.encode(payload, secret_key, 'algorithm'), where 'algorithm' could be HMAC, RSA, ECDSA, etc.

Comment: The method signature also accepts `header_fields` (JOSE Headers) although I agree that in this case dropping them is probably the right choice. This however does nto answer the question since as you identified the issue is with `JWT#decode` which is not currently present in the post.